# Use regex lookarounds (Java version) to extract columns from csv using non capture groups

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

Trying to solve a simple problem, but struggling to understand how to pattern match properly.

I've tried `(?<=,).*?(?=,)`

And my test string is: `"AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EE""E","FFF","GGGGG","HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH"`

I have a non standard quoted csv file, where there can be double quotes within the double quotes of each column.

So I need to use regex to extract each column using non-capture groups and look-arounds, as I can't use capture/match groups

So I need a bunch of different expressions, to capture ONLY the following results:

"AAA"

"BBB"

"CCC"

"DDD"

"EE""E"

"FFF"

etc.

The csv might contain 50 or so columns and the above is just a representative example

Comment: Why not just split by comma?

Comment: Or perhaps `(?<="),(?=")`

Comment: I think @markalex 's solution would be the cleanest for a regex solution using `#split`, but it won't automatically feed you the groups (and you'll need to remove the leading `"` from `split[0]` and the trialing `"` from `split[split.length - 1]`).

Comment: @Rogue, qoutes will stay in place for all elements of split. `(?<=...)` and `(?=...)` are non-capturing, so split wouldn't touch any of the quotes.

Comment: @markalex man I'm off my game today. You're correct, they would all have the surrounding quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've said, all the fields are double-quoted. Seems like you should match the quoted strings rather than focusing on the commas (there might be commas appearing in the middle of a field).

Absolute easiest would be to find all `"(""|[^"]*)*"`, and then clean up the double quotes in a postprocessing step.

Looks pretty awful with the escapes in place!

```java
   String input = "\"AAA\",\"BBB\",\"CCC\",\"DDD\",\"EE\"\"E\",\"FFF\",\"GGGGG\",\"HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH\"";

   List<String> cleanMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
   Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"((\"\"|[^\"]*)*)\"").matcher(input);

   while (m.find()) {
     // Replace the doubled double-quotes with single double-quotes.
     // group(1) does not include the enclosing quotes.

     cleanMatches.add(m.group(1).replace("\"\"", "\""));
   }
```

Outputs:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EE"E
FFF
GGGGG
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

Comment: This would incorrectly match an escaped quote in the double quotes (so `"Hello\"World"` would fail).

Comment: @Rogue The question illustrates that the particular CSV format is using doubled-up quotes to insert double-quotes. e.g. `hello "world"` would be encoded as `"hello ""world"""`. This is actually the method recommended in [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) (nominally the standards document for CSV)

Comment: Good catch, I indeed missed that. In testing the double-quotes, however, it does match the two pieces of the string as separate groups (so `"Hello""World"` becomes the captures `Hello` and `World`, instead of `Hello""World`). A correction that worked for me could be `"((?:[^"]|"")*)"`, which then would require that post-processing step you mentioned.

Comment: @Rogue There will still need to be a postprocessing stage to get rid of the doubled-up quotes, but, yes it becomes a little bit cleaner if we add an outer capture group. Sample code added. fwiw the previous version of the regex did have an error: needs to be `""|[^"]*` rather than `[^"]*|""`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution using split:

```java
String input = "\"AAA\",\"BBB\",\"CCC\",\"DDD\",\"EE\"\"E\",\"FFF\",\"GGGGG\",\"HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH\"";

String[] columns = input.split("(?<=\"),(?=\")");
for(String column : columns){
    System.out.println(column);
}
System.out.println("------");
for(String column : columns){
    System.out.println(column.replaceAll("(?<!\")\"", ""));
}
```

Expected output:

```
"AAA"
"BBB"
"CCC"
"DDD"
"EE""E"
"FFF"
"GGGGG"
"HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH"
------
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EE"E
FFF
GGGGG
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

Here `(?<=\"),(?=\")` looks for commas surrounded by quotes, and splits by them.

Also you can see how to strip both outer quotes and quotes escapement.

`(?<!\")\"` means any quotes, that is not preceded by another quote.